# How can I enable smart mining in my daemon?

Tags: daemon, smart-mining

The most recent 0.10.2 release has an option for smart mining, how would i use this proper?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two new optional parameters for the  start_mining command.

Before:
start_mining [address] [threads]

Now:
start_mining [address] [threads] [do_smart_mining] [ignore_battery]

If you pass the value "true" to the do_smart_mining parameter, then mining will only be activated when you're computer is idle AND plugged into a power source, and will only mine to a certain CPU threshold (40% I believe).

The ignore_battery parameter was added since there's no unified way to get power stats for every system, so on some systems determining if your computer is plugged in fails. If you set this parameter to "true" AND the code fails to query whether you're plugged in or not, then it will perform the smart mining as above, but ignoring the battery requirement.